# Can a skip trowel texture finish affect the overall straightness or linearity of a wall?

Tags: drywall

We're remodeling our home. The construction crew just put up drywall on the new walls to prime.

I noticed the framing around the newly installed windows are off, by 1/8" to 1/2". The foreman said the miss-measurements are because of the skip trowel texture finish we chose (to match the walls of the original existing home areas). As I investigated by measuring further areas (using my levels, plumb Bob, and good old-fashioned measuring tape), I noticed that the newly constructed walls, not just the new window framing are crooked (vertically & horizontally along where our new baseboards are to be positioned).

The foreman just keeps defending that all the structures are "plumb& straight", but the skip trowel texture is the reason.

Is this true?

[image]!

Comment: This pic is a newly constructed area (from ground up) of a new wall with new window. From the glass outward, there is the glass window, then a thick window frame, followed by a thinner window frame/casing. The drywall (with skip trowel texture finish & primed) been added around the entire window, frame, & casing. From the top right corner, the thinner layer starts out about 1/4" and begins to thicken downward & to the left (1/2"). I think either the drywall, the wooden fur between the wooden framing & drywall, or the wooden framing is crooked.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, No it is not because of the wall texture.

The window jamb ( framing ) should have been installed to match the window frame regardless of weather or not the rough opening or the window was installed plumb and true. So your contractor is saying that the jamb was installed to match the window but the texture person put an uneven layer of texture mud resulting in a nearly 1/2" discrepancy. ?? ( unlikely ).

It is the foreman who is responsible for  building a straight and plumb walls, a reasonably plumb and true rough opening and installing the window absolutely plumb and true.

**Ultimately it is the contractor,   the foreman's boss, who is responsible for the work being done.**

**Have you spoke with the contractor ?**

> I noticed that the newly constructed walls, not just the new window
>   framing are crooked (vertically & horizontally along where our new
>   baseboards are to be positioned).

If the foreman did not care enough to make the walls straight, plumb and true then they probably did not care enough to install the rough opening, window and jamb correctly.

Ask the contractor to **explain and demonstrate** how the texture is responsible for the problems you see in the sub-par quality of the construction. If you are not satisfied with the explanation than tell them you are going to hire a consultant to confirm the quality, or lack of quality, of the work.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is exactly how I feel and am pursuing.